# What is the syntax for an Angular / TypeScript method that uses fat arrow syntax *and* declares the return type?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularjs-scope

I'm using Angular 6. In the following, simplified code, I have a method named getActive(). In that method I would like to access the value of `this.active`, however the `this` object is not in scope.

How can I apply fat arrow syntax to this so the value of `this.active` will be accessible inside the method?  I have scoured the web and tried every possible syntax I can think of, but none of them will compile.

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

  active: boolean;   
  isActive: Observable<boolean> = this.getActive();

  constructor() {
      this.active = false;
  }

  getActive(): Observable<boolean> {
      return of(this.active);
  }

}
```

Note that my app works perfectly when I manually set the return value within the `getActive()` method, for example: `return of(false);`  It's just that it can't access the value of `this.active`.

Comment: How does `getActive` get invoked ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir: I've edited the original question to show how `getActive` gets invoked.

Comment: Ok, different problem from the one I thought, I will edit my answer shortly.

Comment: I should note that the value of `this.active` does change periodically.  In my template, I reference `isActive` using an async pipe.  The idea is that changes in the value of `this.active` will be reflected in the view.  It's possible that the above code isn't the right approach.  I am still learning observables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not due to the binding of `this` or arrow functions, it is due to the order of initialization. The field initializers get called first (and thus the `getActive` method is invoked) and only then is the rest of the constructor executed. You can see this in the generated code for `es5`:

```
var PlayerComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
    function PlayerComponent() {
        this.isActive = this.getActive(); // active not set yet
        this.active = false;
    }
    PlayerComponent.prototype.getActive = function () {
        return of(this.active);
    };
    return PlayerComponent;
}());
```

The simplest solution would be to move initialization of the observable in the constructor where you can control the order:

```
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {

    active: boolean;
    isActive: Observable<boolean>;

    constructor() {
        this.active = false;
        this.isActive = this.getActive();
    }

    getActive(): Observable<boolean> {
        return of(this.active);
    }

}
```